# Custom Pytest HTML report title

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

How do I customize the title of the pytest HTML report file based on site I'm automating automatically? For example "site A = title A", "site B = title B".

Below is my conftest.py

```py
def pytest_html_report_title(report):
    report.title = "Site A"
    # report.title = "Site B" (commented out)

driver = None

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser", action="store", default="chrome")


WEBSITE NUMBER 1/SITE A
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup_Medadminportal(request):
    global driver
    browser_name = request.config.getoption("browser")
    if browser_name == "chrome":
        service = Chrome()
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    elif browser_name == "edge":
        service = Edge()
        options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
        driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service, options=options)
    elif browser_name == "firefox":
        print("Firefox")
    driver.get("https://test-admin.mednefits.com/login")
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='login_email']").send_keys("")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='login_password']").send_keys("")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='kt_login_signin_submit']").click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.quit()


WEBSITE NUMBER 2/SITE B
@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup_MedHRportal(request):
    global driver
    browser_name = request.config.getoption("browser")
    if browser_name == "chrome":
        service = Chrome()
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
    elif browser_name == "edge":
        service = Edge()
        options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
        driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service, options=options)
    elif browser_name == "firefox":
        print("Firefox")
    driver.get("https://test-hr.mednefits.com/login")
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Email']").send_keys("")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Continue']").click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Password']").send_keys("")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='kt_login_signin_submit']").click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: This code has quite a lot of duplication. I would recommend reviewing the pytest docs and refactoring in a way that leverages fixtures more. During this process the answer should become quite apparent -- https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#back-to-fixtures

Comment: Im sorry im new to selenium and python, i can't figure it out. Are you able to help?